# vuex with 2 components not updating

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

can someone help me with the lifecycle of this?

I have 2 vue components 1. has a button (Header.vue)

and 2. is sidebar that I want to hide/show depends on value

header looks like this

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a role="button" class="navbar-burger is-pulled-left" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false"
               @click='getToggleSidebarMobile'>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item " href="/">
                <img :src="'/../images/logo.png'">
            </a>


        </div>

        <div class="navbar-end is-pulled-right">
            <div class="navbar-item">

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    import {store} from '../store';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                    hideSidebarMobile: store.state.hideSidebarMobile
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getToggleSidebarMobile(){
                this.hideSidebarMobile = !this.hideSidebarMobile;
                store.dispatch('getToggleSidebarMobile', this.hideSidebarMobile);
            }
        }


    }
</script>
```

sidebar is bigger but trimmed version is this:

```
<template>
    <aside class="menu " v-bind:class="{'is-hidden-touch' : store.state.hideSidebarMobile}" >
....
</aside>
</tamplate>
....
        data() {
            return {
                sidebar: {
                    hideSidebarMobile: store.state.hideSidebarMobile
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getToggleSidebarMobile(){
                store.dispatch('getToggleSidebarMobile');
            }
...
```

update: store.js added

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    hideSidebarMobile: true
},
actions: {
    getToggleSidebarMobile(context, payload){
        console.log("action "+payload)
        context.commit('getToggleSidebarMobile', payload)
    }
},
mutations: {
    getToggleSidebarMobile(state, data){
        state.hideSidebarMobile = data;
        console.log("Mutation "+data);
    }
},
getters: {
    getToggleSidebarMobile(state){
        return state.hideSidebarMobile;
    }
},
```

I also tried to use in template v-bind:class="{'is-hidden-touch' : sidebar.hideSidebarMobile}", but no luck in there as well, as I can see values are updated but I'm unable to add/remove that class where did I go wrong?

updated... forgot to upload store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `store.state.hideSidebarMobile` reference in the sidebar's template is not going to work. (Unless you've set a `store` property on the sidebar's Vue instance equal to the Vuex store, which I'm assuming you haven't.)

If you've registered the Vuex module properly:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({ ... }); // your store config
Vue.use(Vuex); // registering the plugin
new Vue({ // your root Vue instance
  el: '#app',
  store: store, // passing the `store` so components can reference this.$store
  ...
});
```

then you should be able to reference the store in your sidebar component via `this.$store`. Which also means that there is no need to import `store` into every file that needs to reference it.

So in your template:

```
v-bind:class="{'is-hidden-touch' : $store.state.hideSidebarMobile}"
```

Comment: since this is an laravel project, I did
import {store} from './store' and store: store
and it worked... thanks